# Spring MVC: in which situation would be useful to have several DispatcherServlet - Contexts?

Tags: spring-mvc, dispatcher, applicationcontext

Spring MVC documentation says that it is possible to have several DispatcherServlets in a Web application, each one would have a separate context. I wonder in which situation this would be useful? Also, why separated contexts? Could someone give some insight about this?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow this question.

[Can I use Spring MVC and Spring WS in one single application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078795/can-i-use-spring-mvc-and-spring-ws-in-one-single-application)

This should answer your question.

Please follow another question

[Spring - When should I consider loading another context in same JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428439/spring-when-should-i-consider-loading-another-context-in-same-jvm)

This should answer your second question.

Comment: Thank you for your response, that's what I needed, an example of a situation in which two or more DispatcherServlets are required. I was asking also, why has each dispatcher a separate spring context?. Maybe the explanation is obvious, but I don't see it.

Comment: I mean, where is the need of having two separated contexts?

Comment: @alderaan - i have updated answer. please have a look at it. Hope it solves your second problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, Its possible to have several Dispatcher Servlet, Say for example in one of my project I m using Json, Ibatis and normal spring configuration. For each one I m using each dispatcher servlet. But the main dispatcher servlet would be one in which other two would be included.
Its just for convinient.